# The Foundation of Mathematics

Tags: logic, axioms, foundations, philosophy

How can mathematics be so useful if it is based on unproved axioms ?
And what is the nature of axioms that can be used in mathematics ?... I mean obviously I can't invent a set of axioms arbitrarily, and start developping new maths based on them. So what enables mathematics to be that useful ?

Comment: *I mean obviously I can't invent a set of axioms arbitrarily, and start developping new maths based on them.* Why not? This is far from obvious; it is wrong.

Comment: There is more than one foundation for mathematics.

Comment: Well, you would have to regard some things as true to make deductions. The trick is to find a way to assume as little as we can.

Comment: *How can mathematics be so useful if it is based on unproved axioms?* Consider model theory. Before a model of a theory can be used, the axioms are proven for that model.

Comment: well one must end up with unproved axioms anyway, otherwise you'll continue for ever no reaching any foundation at all.

Comment: One area of mathematics can have completely different, even contradictory axioms to another area of mathematics. Consider the three types of geometry.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as off-topic.  This is, in my opinion, not a question about mathematics.  Rather, it is question about the philosophy of mathematics.  As such, I don't think that it is really within the scope of MSE.  You might try [philosophy.se].

Comment: GIGO (garbage in, garbage out). You can start with arbitrary axioms, but if the axioms are garbage, you will get garbage and useless junk. The current axioms we usually accept is the result of years of natural selection, if they do not produce something useful, they will ultimately get forgotten...

Comment: I want to clarify something when I said that I cannot develop maths based on arbitrarily axioms. I don't mean any kind of math, but the useful math we are familiar with. After all mathematicians did not select any system of axioms but they chose specific ones for some reasons (mostly because it best describes the world around us). Assuming that I did not respect the content I should put on this community question section, I give my apologies for that. I just chose to post it here because I am expecting a clear answer.

Comment: This is a very thoughtful and important question about the foundation of mathematics. I don't know why the site moderators put this on hold. Doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original motive for axioms was that if we can agree on some truths, we can deduce others from them. Euclid popularized the use of axioms for geometry, but alternatives to his axioms were developed in the 1800s. Since then, mathematics has moved on from axioms being "true" to their being something whose consequences we choose to investigate. Are the axioms of group theory "true"? That's the wrong question: they're true by definition *of* groups - in fact, they're *the definition of* groups.

A [deductive system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system#Deductive_inference) is a set of propositions, including certain axioms and closed under certain rules of inference. Mathematics doesn't have to settle on one "canonical" list of axioms, because we're interested in many deductive systems. For example, group theory is a deductive system that tells you what is true of whatever satisfies the definition of a group.

Which mathematics will be useful? It's tempting to say the mathematics that happens to describe the real world is useful. But I think it would be better to say that the claims made about the real world with such mathematics are useful insofar as they are true (or at least [probably approximately true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probably_approximately_correct_learning)). When physicists concluded the universe's geometry isn't Euclidean, that wasn't Euclidean geometry's "fault"; if anything, it's the universe's fault for not being Euclidean.

Mathematicians do occasionally need to reconsider which axioms to use. I'm not enough of a historian of mathematics to know whether Russell's paradox led to a shift from one list of set theory axioms to another, or whether axioms weren't in use in the first place, but either way it led to the development of modern axiomatic systems such as ZFC. But it takes something pretty rare for this to happen, such as an inconsistency in Russell's case, or a realisation we had assumed more things than we'd admitted, such as when it was realised "Euclidean geometry" assumes more than his five explicit axioms.